# SQL Server CROSS JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN and OVER with PARTITION summary

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use a cross join to make sure I get rows for each combination of chart of accounts and fiscal periods. The query below works, sort of, but I need to refine the SUM(amount) to include only relevant data. The first sample returns a result.  The second one pops an error that I'm having trouble resolving

This works (sort of)

```
SELECT
    gl.companyId, gl.profitCenterId, gl.projectId, gl.projectGroupId,    
    gl.fiscalId, gl.coaId,
    SUM(gl.amount) sumAmountForRow
FROM 
    fiscal
CROSS JOIN 
    coa, gl
WHERE 
    gl.coaId >= 40000 AND gl.coaId < 50000 AND gl.fiscalId = 311
GROUP BY   
    gl.companyId, gl.profitCenterId, gl.projectId, gl.projectGroupId,
    gl.fiscalId, gl.coaId
ORDER BY  
    gl.coaId
```

[image]

This doesn't work and throws an error:

```
SELECT
    gl.companyId, gl.profitCenterId, gl.projectId, gl.projectGroupId,     
    gl.fiscalId, gl.coaId,
    SUM(gl.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY gl.companyId, gl.profitCenterId, gl.projectId, gl.projectGroupId, gl.fiscalId, gl.coaId) AS sumAmountForRow
FROM 
    fiscal
CROSS JOIN 
    coa, gl
WHERE 
    gl.coaId >= 40000 AND gl.coaId < 50000 AND gl.fiscalId = 311
GROUP BY  
    gl.companyId, gl.profitCenterId, gl.projectId,
    gl.projectGroupId, gl.fiscalId, gl.coaId
ORDER BY  
    gl.coaId
```

Error is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
>   Column 'gl.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks for help!

Per request, tables fiscal and coa

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fiscal] 
(
    [Id]           INT          NOT NULL,
    [description]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [openOrClosed] NVARCHAR(1)  NULL,
    [dateFrom]     DATE         NULL,
    [dateTo]       DATE         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_fiscal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[coa] 
(
    [Id]              INT          NOT NULL,
    [description]     NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [accountType]     NVARCHAR(1)  NULL,
    [statementType]   INT          NULL,
    [jobCostCategory] NVARCHAR(1)  NULL,
    [accountCategory] INT          NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_coa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Why are you mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 syntax? you have `CROSS JOIN coa,gl` why does the object `gl` have to *suffer* the ANSI-89 syntax?

Comment: Sample data and expected results (**not** images) will greatly help us help you. That image does very little to explain what your underlying data is, or what the results you are after are.

Comment: I also suggest some *good* use of whitespace and line breaks. There's no white space at all to speak of, and the line breaks seem a bit haphazard (for example, in the middle of the `PARTITION BY` in the second query). You also appear to have a missing right parenthesis (`)`) in your second query; so I'm surprised it's giving you that error, and not `Incorrect syntax near OVER`.

Comment: I've corrected the parenthesis issue, thanks for pointing that out. Same error however.

Comment: You are looking for fiscalId=311 only, there is no point to have the cross join. You just need the table coa and group by the fields you have.

Comment: Can yo post the table structure of fiscal in case it has columns other than fiscalId

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to include the group by in the second query, the partitioning in the window does the job of the grouping (in a sense).  so the sum(gl.amount) isn't actually associated with that 'outer' group by, which is why you're getting the error.  your query looks like it might otherwise return what you want